# How to optionally choose the filter from url filtering vuejs

Tags: vue.js, url, filter, axios, vuex

I'm using vuejs and vuex for creating my project and I want to optionally choose filter out of this url filters. For ex: when i want to choose only city and car filter, there will be only city and car url's (...?city_id=2&car__car_model=11), but now, when I'm send id's to this action, I should send id's I want and others as blank ('') and then output is ...?city_id=2&sub_category=&sub_category=&car__car_model=&limit=&offset=.
That's my javascript code:

```
async filteredServices ({ commit, dispatch }, cityId = '', subCat = '', car = '', limit = '', offset = '') {
  const url = 'test/service/' + '?city_id=' + cityId + '&sub_category=' + subCat + '&car__car_model=' + car + '&limit=' + limit + '&offset=' + offset
  console.log('url', url)
  const response = await dispatch('api/test/get', { url }, { root: true })
  if (response.status === 200) {
    commit('setCompanyService', response.data.results)
    console.log('setCompanyService', response.data.results)
  }
},
```

That's my html script code:

```
    applyFilter () {
     this.filteredServices(this.selectedCityId)
    }
```

And I also try to use like this:

```
 async filteredServices ({ commit, dispatch }, form) {
  const url = 'test/service/' + '?city_id=' + form.cityId + '&sub_category=' + form.subCat + '&car__car_model=' + form.car + '&limit=' + form.limit + '&offset=' + form.offset
  const response = await dispatch('api/test/get', { url }, { root: true })
  if (response.status === 200) {
    commit('setCompanyService', response.data.results)
    console.log('setCompanyService', response.data.results)
  }
},
```

and html code script:

```
applyFilter () {
  this.filteredServices({
    cityId: this.selectedCityId,
    car: '',
    subCat: 3360,
    limit: '',
    offset: ''
  })
}
```

And the main question is, How to clear write url filtering with optionally choosing the filter what I want in vuejs vuex actions.